# Confused about how to show research done while applying for MS thesis option

Tags: publications, masters

I will give a little bit of background, I have been working in a space and defense based startup for around 30 months now. I have been involved in a lot of hands on research and have done many projects and have collected a lot of data, but due to it being a startup I couldn't find the time to publish anything. Now due to covid, funding has been stagnant and I feel there's not enough growth here, so I am applying for fall 2022.I have a provisional patent filed and am filing a patent asap. The patent is good and contains complex research, also I am starting to write research papers asap.

I believe I have done good research in the field of catalysis and I am looking to apply to some ambitious universities, but since the patent and papers will take time to publish how can I convincingly show the admission that I have done research in the field. I am taking LOR's from the professor who was a mentor to our startup under whom I have conducted research, and also from my manager in startup who will also write about the research done. Will this be enough or should I apply for spring 2023 with all the necessary research items published? Because I want to get into good schools like Uni of michigan ann harobor, eth zurich etc where they have very good research on catalysts going on.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: If you actually commit to "I am doing publications asap" part, you should be able to get patents by then and also quite feasibly have some of the papers accepted. The problem here, of course, is whether the research is sufficiently wrapped up and whether you don't discover mid-writing that there's more work to be done by the time you won't have resources for that anymore.

Comment: I don't think papers will be accepted because deadlines start from november 15, and the time for the patent to get reviewed is atleast 6 months in India. Any advice on how should I go on about showing my research ?